# Publish Avro data to Kafka from Java stream

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, avro

Java and Kafka are both new to me, so forgive me if this is not a good question.

I have written a Java application that listens to an online feed. Whenever a new event comes in, a method `onEvent` converts the information to an Avro object and writes it to `stdout`:

```
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    Avroevent avroevent = new Avroevent();

    avroevent.setInfo1(event.getInfo1());
    avroevent.setInfo2(event.getInfo2());

    String smgs = avroevent.toString();
    System.out.println(smgs);
}
```

This works as expected. But instead of publishing `avroevent` to `stdout`, I would like to publish it to a Kafka topic called `events`.
I have already installed and started Kafka, created the topic `events` and know how to publish to it from the console and from a file. But I am unsure how to publish from my Java program. Every tutorial that I find seems to do it a little differently...

Comment: What have you tried? Any errors/exceptions?  Like you said, there's several ways to do it, depending exactly on what you want to do.

Comment: The tutorial that worked best for me is [this one](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-producer/index.html). My two problems: (1) How do I use Avro data instead of strings? (2) I think I should create only one producer, instead of creating a new one for each event. Could I do that in an `onStart` method that is run when streaming begins?

Comment: Seen this example? https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/specific-avro-producer

Comment: Ha! That worked! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.